# Determine functional dependicies

Tags: database, functional-dependencies

[image: picture]

possible answers:

```
A->B
C->D
A->C
C->A
B->C
```

I think only

```
A->B
A->C
```

are correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**: A -> B and A -> C are the only possible functional dependencies.

Well a functional dependency *X -> Y* means that if for two rows the *X* values are the same, then the *Y* values should be the same as well.

For *A -> B* that holds: the only value that is duplicated is a2. In both cases it maps to b3.

*C -> D* cannot be a functional dependency, because for c3, there are different d's.

When we analyze *A -> C*, we see that this is a potential functional dependency, because the only value in A that occurs twice (a2) again maps on the same value in the C column.

*C -> A* on the other hand is *not* a functional dependency. The value c3 occurs two times and maps to a1 and a5.

Finally *B -> C* also can't be a functional dependency: b1 maps to both c1 and c4.